# How to pass a generic argument to an Object consuming method?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a method foo with a generic argument `<T>` that need to be passed to a `Object` consuming bar method. Why we need to cast to `Object`, everything extends `Object`?

```
fun <T> foo(arg:T) {
    bar(arg)            //doesn't compile
    bar(arg as Object)  //compiles only with cast to Object
}

fun  bar(x:Object){}
```

Comment: Why `Object` instead of `Any`?

Comment: Cause I am a Java pro and a Kotlin noob!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified any upper bound for `T`. Therefore the implied upper bound is used: `T: Any?`.

The function `bar()` takes an `Object` and `Any?` is not assignment-compatible with it. `Object` is one specific subtype of `Any?`.

Another specific subtype of `Any?` is `Int` and it is not also a subtype of `Object`. A non-nullable `Int` compiles into the JVM primitive type `int`, which clearly isn't an instance of `Object`.

Finally, you should reconsider the usage of `Object` anywhere in Kotlin; my IDE immediately flags it with a warning. So, declare

```
fun bar(x: Any?) { }
```

or, if you want to enforce non-nullability,

```
fun bar(x: Any) { }
```

In the latter case you must also constrain the upper bound for `T`:

```
fun <T: Any> foo(arg: T) { ... }
```

However, the example code you posted doesn't even motivate the generic parameter `T`, so possibly all you need is

```
fun foo(x: Any) { ... }
```